# MIPS MARS Calculating crc for given text file. Changing crc 32 into crc 16 and crc 8

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

At the beginning I must say that I am new to mips assembly lanuguge as well as to Stackoverflow.

I have working code for mips assembly language which is calculating crc 32 with a look-up table for given text file and I want to change it for calculating crc 16 and crc 8.

I am almost sure that the look-up table is properly generated for all cases: crc 32, crc 16 and crc 8. I know that I should change the initializing value for crc 16 for example `0xffff`, but it's not enough. I think the problem is that after changing this value this algorithm takes the wrong indexes from the look-up table, am I right?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
##### This subroutine first generates 256 words crc32 table for ASCII codes and then computes the actual crc32 checksum of the file
input:
$a1 = block
$v0 = length
output:
$v0 = crc32 checksum

crc32_checksum:
    li      $t0, 0xedb88320         # CRC32 code generator
    #li     $t0, 0xa001     # CRC16 code generator
    #li     $t0, 0x8c       # CRC8 code generator

    la      $t1, crc_tab        # address of the table to fill in

    li      $t2, 0      # load 0 into $t2

tab_gen:
    move    $t3, $t2        # move counter of 8 digit hex values packed into table to $t3

    li  $t4, 8      # digit/bit counter equals 8

tab_byte:
    and     $t5, $t3, 1     # AND data with 1
    beqz    $t5, shift      # branch to 'shift' if equal 0

    srl     $t3, $t3, 1     # shift right data
    xor     $t3, $t3, $t0   # XOR both values (shifted data with CRC polynomial)
    b       next        # branch to next 

shift:
    srl     $t3, $t3, 1     # shift right data

next:
    sub     $t4, $t4, 1     # decrese digit/bit counter
    bnez    $t4, tab_byte   # branch if byte/bit counter is not equal to zero

    sw      $t3, 0($t1)     # store 8 digit hex value
    add     $t1, $t1, 4     # move to the next address to be fill


    add     $t2, $t2, 1     # increase counter of 8 digit hex values packed into table
    bltu    $t2, 256, tab_gen   # branch until 256 8 digit hex values are packed into table


#### # Calculate the actual CRC32

    li      $t0, 0xffffffff # initialize crc value for CRC32 code
    #li     $t0, 0x0000     # initialize crc value for CRC16 code
    #li     $t0, 0xffff     # initialize crc value for CRC16 code
    #li     $t0, 0xff       # initialize crc value for CRC8 code

    la      $t1, crc_tab        # point to crc_tab

crc32:
    lbu     $t2, 0($a1)     # load byte of data
    add     $a1, $a1, 1     # advance the data pointer
    xor     $t2, $t2, $t0   # byte of data XOR with crc
    and     $t2, $t2, 0xff  # (byte of data XOR with crc) AND with 0xff (to produce a table index)
    sll     $t2, $t2, 2         # scale (*4) the index because of addressing 32-bit words
    add     $t2, $t2, $t1   # form the final address in the table

    lw      $t2, 0($t2)     # load a value from the table
    srl     $t3, $t0, 8     # crc shifted 8 bits right
    xor     $t0, $t2, $t3   # XOR both values (i.e. shifted crc and the value read from the table)


    sub     $v0, $v0, 1     # decrement the byte counter
    bnez    $v0, crc32      # repeat untill all bytes of data are processed

    not     $v0, $t0        # invert all bits of final crc

    move    $t7, $v0

    jr      $ra     # jump to return address
```

Comment: I added here the subroutine which generates the 256 words crc32 table for ASCII codes.
I think that this CRC 32 implementation is done like here:  [link]http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-CRCAppendix.html

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest that you better define your goals.  There is no single "CRC 16" nor single "CRC 8". Take a look at this [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Commonly_used_and_standardized_CRCs), and then decide which flavor of CRC16 and CRC8 you wish to implement.  (Without additional information, I would guess that you are interested in the CCITT versions.  They are most prevelant in my experience.)

Once you know where you are going, try googling "ccitt 16 pseudocode" for some tips on the 16-bit algorithm.  The [Dr. Dobbs link](http://www.drdobbs.com/implementing-the-ccitt-cyclical-redundan/199904926) is good, as well as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) and [this one](http://www.academia.edu/5218887/Implementing_CRC16-CCITT_Checksum_Calculator_Algorithm_on_FPGA) (although it is geared more toward hardware implementations). The 8-bit algorithm can be researched similarly.  Try "ccitt 8 algorithm".  [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19059/C-CCITT-8-CRC-Algorithm) is reasonable.

Once you gain a grasp of the pseudocode, then you're in a better position to implement it in assembler.

Comment: Thanks for response. The thing is I would like to implement any version of CRC 32bit, 16bit and 8bit, but In one quite compact program.
I found also such site: [link]http://www.sanity-free.com/12/crc32_implementation_in_csharp.html
    There are implementations for crc32, crc16 and crc8.